# Making document classes in LyX available

Tags: lyx, document-classes, letters

I'm writing a letter in LyX, and I want to choose a document class for it. (I don't like the default `letter`.)

Looking at `Document -> Settings -> Document class`, I see that most classes are "unavailable". For example, `Unavailable: Letter (KOMA-script)`. How do I make those available?

I tried installing the `koma-script` package in the MiKTeX package manager, but it didn't help.

**EDIT:**

Here's the dialog I get when doing `Reconfigure`:

---

### LyX: System reconfiguration failed

The system reconfiguration has failed.
Default textclass is used but LyX may not be able to work properly.

### Please reconfigure again if needed.

### OK

Comment: Go to tools and then choose reconfigure

Comment: Windows XP, LyX 1.6.7. (Don't know what "TeX distribution" means or how I find it out.)

Comment: Did you refresh the file name database? (General tab in MikTeX options.)

Comment: It is okay you edited your answer with this details. Do the reconfigure and restart LyX

Comment: @Torbjörn: The package manager of MiKTeX does it by default

Comment: See my edit now.

Comment: @cool-RR: you should have a local directory lyx, don't know where it is located on a Windows-system. However, there is a `configure.log` file which should you show what goes wrong. Search for the file.  Could it be that you have running LyX twice?

Answer (score 6):

From the LyX Wiki, [Trouble Configuring LyX (missing classes) with MikTeX](http://wiki.lyx.org/Windows/LyXWinTips#toc10):

> MiKTeX can cause problems with the configure script in LyX if the "Install missing packages on-the-fly" option is checked. If you find that only a few classes are available in LyX under Windows, try disabling this option in the MiKTeX general options (mo.exe) and re-configuring LyX.

So start MiKTeX options (start menu or mo.exe) and choose No (rather not not "Ask me first") for the option "Install missing packages on-the-fly", as recommended in the [MiKTeX 2.9 issues](http://miktex.org/2.9/issues) (actually for TeXnicCenter compatibility), valid also for MiKTeX 2.8. If necessary, install manually using the MiKTeX package manager, and reconfigure LyX.

Here's a screenshot of the options window:

[image: MiKTeX options]